# JQ: How to specify function name and include file as input arguments?

Tags: command-line, jq

I want to create generic SH script which will be called with a specified function to be used in the middle of JQ query.

**1. How can I call a function by name specified as command-line argument?**

The straightforward way do so generates string with function name instead of invoking such a function:

```
jq --arg query_function "foo_function" '
  include "foo_function";
  . |
  ($query_function)' \
input.txt
```

---

**2. Is it possible to also specify a file to include with a command-line argument to JQ?**

I also tried to do it in a straightforward manner, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither jq function names nor module names can be specified as jq variables, and so to achieve what you seem to want, you would have to resort to shell string-interpolation, or lookup expressions.

It is worth noting, however, that jq supports array-based path expressions, and so certain kinds of lookups can be supported using jq variables.